# When I run android studio 2.2.3 these messsage is shown and unable to run my project.How i can solve?

Tags: android, android-studio

```
[Error:Could not open cp_settings remapped class cache for 9y1gfkloc4c02whxatii4koij (C:\Users\Romeo\.gradle\caches\2.14.1\scripts-remapped\settings_8umapvcc1eiwcf8bhkwspawmz\9y1gfkloc4c02whxatii4koij\cp_settings57408229).
 Could not open cp_settings generic class cache for settings file 'I:\constraint-layout-master\constraint-layout-master\constraint-layout-start\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\Romeo\.gradle\caches\2.14.1\scripts\9y1gfkloc4c02whxatii4koij\cp_settings\cp_settings57408229).
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Romeo\.gradle\caches\2.14.1\scripts\9y1gfkloc4c02whxatii4koij\cp_settings\cp_settings57408229\cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified][1]
```

Comment: go to File-->click invalidate caches & restart  , wait till studio restarts ,and check if working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to the C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\2.x\n directory and delete the "scripts" and "scripts-remapped" folders and for safety u can save this folders in another directory in case anything wrong place it back. Then sync your project with gradle file. when sync your project it will automatic generate new cache files. it might work.
If it doesn't work then go to C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\ and delete your 2.14.1 folder and restart android studio.
Also update the gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

File->Invalidate Caches/Restart".